# How to change name of the folders when copying multiple folders in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, copy

This is my code right now:

```
[int]$NumberOfProfiles = Read-Host "Enter the number of Portable Firefox profiles You need"
$WhereToWrite = Read-Host "Enter the full path where You'd like to install the profiles" 
$Source = Get-Location 
$FolderName = "JonDoFoxPortable"
$SourceDirectory = "$Source\$Foldername"
$Copy = Copy-Item $SourceDirectory $WhereToWrite -Recurse -Container
while ($NumberOfProfiles -ge 0) {$Copy; $NumberOfProfiles--}
```

As You can see right now it just overwrites the folders, but I'd need it to copy certain amount of folders that is declared in `$NumberOfProfiles` (e.g. `$NumberOfProfiles = 10`) and it makes JonDoFoxPortable1, JonDoFoxPortable2 ... JonDoFoxPortable10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
while ($NumberOfProfiles -ge 0) {
  $DestinationDirectory = Join-Path $WhereToWrite "$Foldername$NumberOfProfiles"
  Copy-Item $SourceDirectory $DestinationDirectory -Recurse -Container
  $NumberOfProfiles--
}
```

Or, probably even simpler, something like this:

```
0..$NumberOfProfiles | % {
  $DestinationDirectory = Join-Path $WhereToWrite "$Foldername$_"
  Copy-Item $SourceDirectory $DestinationDirectory -Recurse -Container
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it for you:

replace:

```
while ($NumberOfProfiles -ge 0) {$Copy; $NumberOfProfiles--}
```

with:

```
(0..$NumberOfProfiles) | % {
    Copy-Item $SourceDirectory "$WhereToWrite$_" -Recurse -Container
}
```

This will loop around from 0 to `$NumberOfProfiles` and copy to a location named `$WhereToWrite` with the iteration number attached `$_`